# correlated SQL subquery cannot be rewritten?

Tags: sql, subquery

In SQL books there is always statement that "some" correlated subqueries can be rewritten to sequential query or joins. But they never mention which can not. Any examples please?

Comment: Rewritten to what?

Comment: Tell your problem statement where you are facing issue. We will try to help.

Comment: The question is a generic one. I guess you are searching for an example of query that is using correlated subquery and does not have equivalent without using correlation.

Comment: A select list correlated subquery may be rewritten as a left join.

Answer (score 0):

When rows in the correlated subquery match multiple rows in the outer query, then it is quite hard to write this without correlation.  An example is:

```
select a.*,
       (select count(distinct b.x)
        from b
        where b.y = a.y or b.z = a.z
       )
from a;
```

There is probably some way of writing this without a correlation clause, but it would be not be simple.

Perhaps a simpler example is just getting the "next" b after an a:

```
select a.*,
       (select min(b.date)
        from b
        where b.date > a.date            
       )
from a;
```

There are ways to write this, but it would be much more complicated and the naive methods, more expensive.